# Grouping similar PDF files in folders using python

Tags: python, pdf, grouping, data-extraction

I have a folder with a bunch of scanned invoices in PDF formats. I want to group these PDF files into separate folders; separate folder for each supplier name.

(supplier name can be usually seen at the top of the page like a "letter head" or sometimes it may be confined to smaller area at the top)

I am planning to write a `.py` script for this grouping purpose but I am not sure which approach will work.

Can I use `OpenCV` image processing to read PDF as images and then train a model to classify using any machine learning classifier?

Is there any other better approaches that I could try out?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by exploring pdf parsing with [Tika](https://pypi.org/project/tika/). OpenCV seems like an overkill for your problem.